# How to insert data from one table to another table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a two table  '`Inventory`' and  '`Tendor`' where Inventory has primary key `pk_id` ,i updated '`Inventory`' table when `Inventory.ti_name = Tendor.ki_name` by using following query

```
Update Inventory A set (Used_NAME, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ti_STATUS)
 =    (Select B.Using_NAME, B.ACCOUNT_NO,  B.ki_STATUS from 
Tendor B where A.ti_name = B.ki_name and a.pk_id is not null);
```

Anything wrong in this query or any optimized one??

After updation for those who is not satisfying the condition `Inventory.ti_name = Tendor.ki_name` i want to insert it as new rows in '`Inventory`' table with primary key `pk_id` should be changed
how to do this? for `pk_id` do i need to do some logic like '`SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL'`
Can anybody suggest a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query updates searches matching rows in tables `inventory` and `tendor`. When both tables contain row with the same value of `ki_name`, it updates row in table `inventory`. All rows from `tendor`, that was not found in `inventory`, will be inserted there:

```
merge into Inventory a
using Tendor b
   on (A.ti_name = B.ki_name)
 when matched then update
  set a.Used_NAME = B.Using_NAME,
      a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.ACCOUNT_NO,
      a.ti_STATUS = B.ki_STATUS
 when not matched then
insert (pk_id, Used_NAME, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ti_STATUS)
values (your_seq.nextval, B.Using_NAME, B.ACCOUNT_NO,  B.ki_STATUS)
```

Also you can use sequence in `insert` statement.

Comment: let me check ,if it works it will be great. i am using oracle

Comment: @Dimitry  'when matched then update' and 'when not matched then' is a oracle query?

Comment: Yes. It is a part of SQL standard, and it is implemented in oracle. More information is in documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Comment: @dimitry in this query 'your_seq.nextval' what is this 'your' stands for? is it a keyword in oracle?

Comment: @peter `your_seq` - I meant "name of your sequence".

Comment: @dimitry it worked wonderfully ,let me do additional tests, both insertion and updation in a single query , you are great